# Use Others with Aggregate in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to return a `word` which is defined as:

```vhdl
subtype word is std_logic_vector(word_len - 1 downto 0);
```

By concatenating a whole bunch of other inputs from a record like so (this is inside a switch block):

```vhdl
return get_opc(ins.op) & std_logic_vector(ins.val) & "0000"; -- TODO Replace these with some sort of others construct
```

However, different opcodes have different sets of other inputs and so the amount that needs to be right-filled with zeroes changes. I'm not a huge fan of manually hardcoding trailing zeroes, it's a mess ad it won't play well if I resize my word.

My instinct was to try:

```vhdl
return get_opc(ins.op) & std_logic_vector(ins.val) & (others => '0');
```

But apparently you can't use `others` as an aggregate in this context.

I know I could create a buffer the size of a word, fill it with zeroes and then slot my different inputs into different slices but AFAIK, that would be extremely verbose, requiring me to specify the start and end point of each slice rather than just concatenating them on the left. This would soon get very messy.

Is there any easy way around this that keeps everything concise?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Your question is of less value to future readers if they can't replicate the problem and evaluate solutions. (Re: Matthew's answer - The ability to have elements of the type of the aggregate as well as it's element type was introduced in -2008 and isn't widely used, limited by synthesis support. The response to your issue #1704 should be the same as to your #1667 an aggregate is an expression and -2008 aggregates aren't fully implemented in ghdl as yet).

Comment: A yes/no question without a [mcve] can get a simple answer (yes, without relying on -2008 aggregates). The subtype of the aggregate with the others choice can't be determined from context for the [specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) with your instinctive attempt. In the function `subtype zeros is std_logic_vector (word_length - ins.op'length - ins.val'length - 1 downto 0);`. Use a qualified expression to specify the aggregate's subtype `return get_opc(ins.op) & std_logic_vector(ins.val) & zeros'(others => '0');` word_length taken from the subtype word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use VHDL-2008 (or VHDL-2019!), you can return an aggregate like this:

```
return (get_opc(ins.op), std_logic_vector(ins.val), others => '0');
```

This assumes that your return type is *constrained*. In other words, this is OK:

```
function F return word is 
begin
  return (get_opc(ins.op), std_logic_vector(ins.val), others => '0');
end function;
```

whereas if your return type is *unconstrained* like this, then it is not OK:

```
function F return std_logic_vector is
```

Comment: this seems to cause a coredump in ghdl... Is it safe enough to assume that this is a GHDL bug rather than a language violation?

Comment: @Persistence Whether, it's a language violation or not, it shouldn't cause a core dump. You should get an error message telling what is wrong.

Comment: I've reported it as a bug on the GHDL issue tracker but thank you for your answer nonetheless